# Fullcalendar - column header in month view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In month view, how can I show in the columns header only the current month?

For example, this is a view of July:

[image]

As you can see, the first 4 columns are still showing June (I guess it's because the first 4 days in the view are in June).

I'm using `ddd, MMM YYYY` format for month in the `columnFormat`

Comment: Why don't you just use `ddd` since the month name is in the header->title?

Comment: @Yuri Because I don't display a header

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add a conditional date format so here's the easiest way. You check the date that is stored in the column header, and if the day is from the previous month, delete the span element from the header. The function is defined in viewRender: in the fullCalendar initialization.

```
viewRender: function() {
    var daysOfWeek = [];
    var tableHeaders = [];

    //collect all table headers
    $(".fc-chrono th").each(function() {
        daysOfWeek.push(moment(this.attr("data-date")).get('date')); //store day, like 31
        tableHeaders.push(this); //store element
    });

    //check if the border between month is somewhere here
    var isBetweenTwoMonths = false;
    var locationOfMonthBorder = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length - 1; i++) {
        if (daysOfWeek[i] > daysOfWeek[i+1]) { // e.g. 31 > 1
            isBetweenTwoMonths = true;
            locationOfMonthBorder = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //now remove all the column header texts up to the first day of next month
    if (isBetweenTwoMonths) {
        for (var i = 0; i < locationOfMonthBorder + 1; i++) {
            tableHeaders[i].find("span.fc-cell-text").remove();
        }
    }
}
```